# React useStyles Remove class name on click

Tags: reactjs, state, jss

This is almost certainly the easiest thing in the world but is somehow evading me....

I have a selection of material-ui card components that are selectable onClick and as such should add a class when it's selected.  For some reason the removal of the class isn't applying despite all the examples seeming to suggest it should.  What am I doing wrong?

Cut down for brevity...

````
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        cardSelected: {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected
        },
    })
);


export const Occasion = (): JSX.Element => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string>('');

    const handleSelect = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        const s = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-option");
        if (s) {
            setSelected(s);
        }
    }

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
            <CardActionArea className={classes.actionArea} onClick={handleSelect} data-option={occasion.id}>
                <Card className={ selected === occasion.id ? classes.cardSelected : '' }>
                    <IconRounded className={classes.iconItem} color="secondary" />
                    <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">{ occasion.name } </Typography>
                </Card>
            </CardActionArea>
        </Grid>
    );
}

```


Clicking a card correctly adds the desired class but does not remove it from the other card items?
````

Comment: Where is the `occasion` variable coming from? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: What I gather from this is that you are mapping over an array and producing multiple Occasion elements? If so, you should store which one is active higher up in the component tree, preferably inside of the component where you are mapping over your array.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to clear the `selected`.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        cardSelected: {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected
        },
    })
);


export const Occasion = (): JSX.Element => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string>('');

    const handleSelect = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        const s = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-option");
        if (s) {
            setSelected(s);
        } else {
            setSelected('');
        }
    }

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
            <CardActionArea className={classes.actionArea} onClick={handleSelect} data-option={occasion.id}>
                <Card className={ selected === occasion.id ? classes.cardSelected : '' }>
                    <IconRounded className={classes.iconItem} color="secondary" />
                    <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">{ occasion.name } </Typography>
                </Card>
            </CardActionArea>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

In the current example, you're just adding it to `selected` if `id` or `s` exists but not removing it.

**EDIT** Updated with toggle functionality.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        cardSelected: {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected
        },
    })
);


export const Occasion = (): JSX.Element => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string>('');

    const toggleSelect = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        const s = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-option");
        if (s && !selected) {
            setSelected(s);
        } else {
            setSelected('');
        }
    }

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
            <CardActionArea className={classes.actionArea} onClick={toggleSelect} data-option={occasion.id}>
                <Card className={ selected === occasion.id ? classes.cardSelected : '' }>
                    <IconRounded className={classes.iconItem} color="secondary" />
                    <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">{ occasion.name } </Typography>
                </Card>
            </CardActionArea>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Comment: BTW, The example is not complete. Where do we get the `occasion` object data?

Comment: I had tried that.  Clearing it before setting it, it doesn't making a difference

Comment: Ah! You need a toggle functionality. If the selected value already exists then you need to clean it! Updated the example. Check the edit part.

Comment: Is the updated solution working?

Comment: Thanks but the issue remains!  All the items seem to retain the 'selected' style even with the toggle version applied.

To be clear, there are multiple cards on the page this is a component being rendered x many times... so only one should ever be selected.